# How to create the PYTHON version of this PHP script. ( reads from php://stdin )

Tags: python

I have a working php script that actually intercepts the incoming e-mail from sendmail and saves it to a file.

here it is:

```
<?php
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
$fdw = fopen("/test/mail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);

?>
```

i have never seen something like this in terms of reading from

```
 php://stdin
```

is there a PYTHON version of this ?

i rather use python than php.

but this php script works fine.

Comment: In a WSGI web application, you would not want to read from stdin. Not sure why you are tagging this with WSGI tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three standard I/O streams in Python are stored in `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr`. They normally never need to be opened, only used.

```
foo = sys.stdin.read(1024)
```

Comment: ... without that `1024` for the example as it is only a chunk size when reading in the loop. I.e. the loop need not to be used in Python. One should be aware it is rather special way of using stdin. Generally, closing a `stdin` makes the same sense as closing the keyboard ;) The same way, waiting for eof from the keyboard does not make too much sense.

Answer (score 2):

sys.stdin.read()  should do it

Answer (score 0):

The whole script in Python:

```
import sys
with open('/test/mail.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(sys.stdin.read())
```